# "Uncaught TypeError: x.toUpperCase is not a function" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function to capitalize onchange like this:

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="id" onchange="capitalize()">
```

And function definition is as follows:

```
<script>
    function capitalize()
    {
        var x= document.getElementById('abc');
        x=x.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById('abc').value=x;
    }
</script>
```

I get the error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: x.toUpperCase is not a function

What changes should I make or should I include any header files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use value to get its value and then convert to upper case:

```
x=x.value.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an **element** into uppercase. You are calling it on the input itself, not the value. If you want the value to become uppercased then you have to use `value`:

```
x= x.value.toUpperCase();
```